# The preferred way to set matplotlib figure/axes properties

Tags: python, matplotlib, idioms

Say I have a matplotlib axes called `ax`, and I want to set several of its properties. Currently, I do it like this:

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_xlabel('some label')
```

But it gets tedious after a while. Then I ran into this method:

```
ax.set(yscale='log', xlim=[0,10], xlabel='some label')
```

Much more concise, but it seems a bit undocumented. I mean all the documentation says is "A tkstyle set command, pass *kwargs* to set properties".

What is the preferred or idiomatic way?
Is the `set` method api stable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) appears to recommend `ax.set_xxx()` functions, but also mentions `.setp(xxx=)`.

On the other hand, `.set(xxx=)` function is not used and `.setp(xxx=)`, while documented, is not used in any examples ([Pyplot API](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api)).

I understand it that matplotlib supports both imperative programming style and matlab-like style. Reason being the target user bases -- those already familiar with Python and those who used Matlab before.

I conclude that matplotlib *recommended* api is `.set_xxx()`.

A quick check through the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) confirms this.

Edit: it appears there are examples of both in the gallery now.

Similar duality exists for keyword arguments to plot functions, except that imperative API is not that obvious.

Comment: Answer covers apparent matplotlib api. I would prefer both options available and documented.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Not sure if `setp(xxx=y)` or `set_xxx(y)` is more "pythonic", but both are not exactly object-oriented approaches; the latter will navigate up and down and across the crazy hierarchy of matplotlib class instances, and sometimes silently set class properties or substitute a simple/numeric input with new class instances (e.g. in `set_xticklabels(y)` passing `y` to `ticker.FixedFormatter(y)`).  Both are only object-oriented-ish.

Comment: [Times change](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set.html).

Comment: Thanks @Alan can you maybe summarise what the recommendation is now?

Comment: IMO, since the docs now include examples of both, you should use what you like/need. I usually use `set` when I have multiple properties to set on a single axes instance.

Answer (score 9):

As a super-late followup to this question:

`ax.set_xlim(4)` and `ax.set(xlim=4)` are ultimately the same thing, so do what you like. `ax.set(kwarg=foo)` calls `ax.set_kwarg(foo)` via some string manipulation, as you can see if you look at the source.  The various setter functions are mostly one-liners, as well, but exist to allow for the introspective `setp` to work.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the pyplot (interactive) interface for matplotlib, which exposes the 
[`setp`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=setp#matplotlib.pyplot.setp) function (which I use very often).

> matplotlib supports the use of setp() (“set property”) and getp() to
>   set and get object properties, as well as to do introspection on the
>   object.

Which lets you do things just like your `set` function above, only you pass the object to set as a parameter:

```
>>> x = arange(0,1.0,0.01)
>>> y1 = sin(2*pi*x)
>>> y2 = sin(4*pi*x)
>>> lines = plot(x, y1, x, y2)
>>> setp(lines, linewidth=2, color='r')
```

I'm guessing the `setp` function actually calls the passed object's `set` function which works to locate and set the *kwargs*.

So my thoughts are, that despite the lack of documentation the object's `set` method is the idiomatic approach for setting multiple parameters via *kwargs* instead of line by line.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with matplotlib backend and so I just came across this post. I was hoping matplotlib would allow for the use of dictionary control for the properties in a plot. Using the suggestion by @Chris Zeh you could:

```
f = {'xlabel': 'x1', 'ylabel': 'x2'}
[setp(ax, formati, formatj) for formati, formatj in f.items()]
```

which solves my problems. Hope this helps.